# Separating controls using GridSplitter does not use 'star'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following code to create a grid with two textblocks and a gridsplitter. On click of a button I collapse the right textblock the space is not taken up by the left textblock. Why?

```
Text1.Text = "Text1";
Text2.Text = "Text2";
split.Width = 3;

Text1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);


Grid ingd = new Grid();
RowDefinition inrow1 = new RowDefinition();
ColumnDefinition inCol1 = new ColumnDefinition();
ColumnDefinition inCol2 = new ColumnDefinition();
ColumnDefinition inCol3 = new ColumnDefinition();
ingd.RowDefinitions.Add(inrow1);
ingd.ColumnDefinitions.Add(inCol1);
ingd.ColumnDefinitions.Add(inCol2);
ingd.ColumnDefinitions.Add(inCol3);

// Width set here as Star for the left textblock
inCol1.Width = new GridLength(10, GridUnitType.Star);
inCol2.Width = new GridLength(3, GridUnitType.Pixel);
inCol3.Width = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto);

ingd.Children.Add(Text1);
ingd.Children.Add(split);
ingd.Children.Add(Text2);

Grid.SetColumn(Text1, 0);
Grid.SetColumn(split, 1);
Grid.SetColumn(Text2, 2);

wrap.Children.Add(ingd);
```

ButtonClick

```
Text2.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed
split.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
```

xaml

```
 <Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <WrapPanel Name="wrap" >
        </WrapPanel>
        <Button Height="100" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
    </Grid>
 </Window>
```

Please note that inCol1 is of type'Star'. If I change the gridlength (first parameter) from 10 to 0, the textblock is not visible at all. Please help. I have made this as an example as my actual application is complicated

Comment: i think, `ingd` is not stretched in `WrapPanel` and `inCol1` is not going to grow. try another type of panel: `Grid`

Comment: I changed the warp panel to grid and that works. But if If I change the gridlength (first parameter) from 10 to 0, the textblock is not visible at all

Comment: `Width = "0*"` = collapsed column. why `0`? anything > 0 is Ok. default is  `1`

Comment: Is there anyway to use wrap panel instead of grid? As suggested, how can I stretch using wrappanel?

Comment: what kind of layout do you need? are there more elements in `WrapPanel`? how `indg` should be positioned?

Comment: In my application the wrappanel has a grid with 3 controls. The application creates dynamic number of grids (which have 3 controls each). The 3 controls are listbox, gripsplitter and tabcontrol. I want the listbox to take all the space when tabcontrol and gridspliiter are collapsed. Even though there are not directly under wrappanel, the space is not taken up

Comment: if you use `StackPanel` (with Vertical orientation), grids will be stacked vertically and stretched horizontally

Comment: Works (nearly) but unfortunately I want the grids horizontally as well as vertically. Also the GridSplitter does not work if I change to stackpanel. Actually in a wrappanel the only time it stops is when the user chages the position of the gridsplitter

Answer (score 0):

> the right textblock the space is not taken up by the left textblock. Why?

The `*` says to fill up all available space as reported to it by the grid. Just because internal control[s] hide themselves, doesn't change the fact that the **column** was *starsized* to **expand** into all available space.

> I want the listbox to take all the space when tabcontrol and gridspliiter are collapsed.

Then you need to make the column of the `ListBox` starsized and the other two columns which are the controls that hide themselves set to `auto`.

Auto sizing, will size the column to the controls whether hidden or not, star sizing sizes to the external specifications of the grid and ignores the internal controls. I believe you have the concepts mixed up.